# Calculating portfolio weights of derivatives

Tags: portfolio, derivatives

A rather simple question.

You have a portfolio of USD100 in cash. You now take USD10 and buy a derivative that gives you exposure of USD200 to something.

What is the weighting of cash in the portfolio now: USD90/USD100 or USD90/USD290?

(You want the weight that you would multiply the asset's return by if you were calculating the portfolio's return.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to calculate your weights using your total exposure, no matter which product you are using. 
In this case, as you said will be 90/290.